# bash regex doesnt match "at least n times but not more than m"

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I'm trying to match string such as: "+99", "-82", "5", "auto" and "max"
==auto and max and numbers(lets say integers) with or without sign

I tried regex

`var='^([+|-]{0,1}[0-9][0-9]*)|(auto)|(max)$'`

but it fails on "at least n times but not more than m" thing, in my case {0,1}
Anyway I tested var='ab{0,1}' and var='ab{2}' and these don't work neither

I didn't get any furher but I thing that the next problem could by these: ()

I'm using #!/bin/bash version 4.2.24(1)

Thanks in advance!

**edit1:**
I don't know how to group this regex for **?** to be working as Karoly Horvath suggested.
I'm using this check function I found somewhere.

```
#!/bin/bash

INTEGER_MAX='^([+-])?[0-9][0-9]*$'

function isNumeric() { 

    check=`echo $1 | sed "s/\($2\)//"`

    if [ -z ${check} ]; then
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}

isNumeric "$1" "$INTEGER_MAX" && echo "passed"
```

**edit2 - SOLVED**

it's working with

`RE='(^([+-])?[0-9]+$)|(^auto$)|(^max$)'`

tested on

`[[ $string =~ $pattern ]] && echo "passed"`

THX!

Comment: you haven't told us how do you use the regex.. different commands expect different regex syntax.

Comment: Are you using the Bash regex matching operator `[[ $string =~ $pattern ]]` or `grep` or what?

Comment: Why don't you replace the complicated looking function with something like `if [[ $1 =~ ^[+-]?[0-9]+$ ]] || [[ $1 =~ ^max$ ]] || [[ $1 =~ ^auto$ ]]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `[+|-]` selector accepts one character which is either `+` `|` or `-`. You probably meant: `[+-]`.

The shorthand for `{0,1}` is `?`, and `[0-9][0-9]*` is simply `[0-9]+`, but of course both should work.

> Anyway I tested var='ab{0,1}' and var='ab{2}' and these don't work
>   neither

`ab{0,1}` means either `a` or `ab`, quantifiers work on the last expression, which is typically a character, or a selector, if you want to apply the quantifier for an expression you have to group it.

If you have further questions please post how you use the regex, cause I'm not sure what your problem is...